# How to .apply() lambda function to restricted column set in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, lambda

I am trying to verify if the lambda function I created is correct, so I added addition columns (max_value, min_value, diff) to verify the numerical value for my lambda function is correct.

But when I did this, I noticed that the resulting lambda expression incorporated these new columns during evaluation, and as a result the diff and lambda column is not correct.

- How do I restrict the .apply() function to columns `b, d, e`?
- Or, is it possible to restrict the lambda function? (not sure if this is logical)

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
frame = DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 3), columns=list('bde'),
                  index=['Utah', 'Ohio', 'Texas', 'Oregon'])
f = lambda x: x.max() - x.min()
frame['max_value'] = np.max(frame, axis=1)
frame['min_value'] = np.min(frame, axis=1)
frame['diff'] = frame.max_value - frame.min_value
frame['lambda']  = frame.apply(f, axis=1)
frame
```

**Results:**

```
Out[30]: 
               b         d         e  max_value  min_value      diff    lambda
Utah    0.382063 -1.026674 -2.706572   0.382063  -2.706572  3.088636  5.795208
Ohio    1.718023 -0.446802 -0.345996   1.718023  -0.446802  2.164825  2.611627
Texas   0.809239 -0.761325 -1.253476   0.809239  -1.253476  2.062715  3.316191
Oregon -1.722270  0.438120 -0.619916   0.438120  -1.722270  2.160390  3.882659
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fairly straight forward to select a subset of columns for processing. Here I use the same selector you used to create the data frame, but it is simply a list of column names.

**Code:**

```
df['lambda'] = df[list('bde')].apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min(), axis=1)
```

**Test Code:**

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 3), columns=list('bde'),
               index=['Utah', 'Ohio', 'Texas', 'Oregon'])
df['max_value'] = np.max(df, axis=1)
df['min_value'] = np.min(df, axis=1)
df['diff'] = df.max_value - df.min_value
df['lambda'] = df[list('bde')].apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min(), axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Results:**

```
               b         d         e  max_value  min_value      diff    lambda
Utah   -0.108325 -0.043782 -0.799588  -0.043782  -0.799588  0.755807  0.755807
Ohio    0.444546 -0.697631  1.226530   1.226530  -0.697631  1.924161  1.924161
Texas  -2.024484 -1.749634  2.110496   2.110496  -2.024484  4.134980  4.134980
Oregon -0.482084 -0.604144  0.701907   0.701907  -0.604144  1.306051  1.306051
```

Comment: Please, don't do list('bde'), that's not Pythonic!

Comment: @DiegoMoraCespedes As I stated, this was the method the OP used, and I did it to keep the context more familiar.  Sorry you find it offensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can access columns inside your lambda function:

```
f = lambda x: x['max_value'] - x['min_value']
```

And if you do not want to use those columns, you can do everything inside your lambda function:

```
frame['lambda']  = frame[['b', 'd', 'e']].apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min(), axis=1)
```

This will apply the lambda function only to the 'b', 'd' and 'e' columns.

Comment: The OP stated that `max_value` and `min_value` are only there to debug.  And the rest of the answer is a copy of the other already present answer.